# How do I convert Command-line script to a windows schedule task?

Tags: php, xampp, scheduled-tasks

I have installed localhost/server in my machine and I need to run a php script using windows schedule task.

I am able to successfully run the php script from the **command line prompt** by exectuing the following commands:

```
cd C:/xampp/htdocs/Version/I7
php index.php cli/reminders
```

I have tried the following for the **scheduled task** but it is not working.

Program Script:

```
‪C:/xampp/php/php.exe
```

Arguments:

```
-f C:/xampp/htdocs/Version/I7/application/controllers/cli/Reminders.php
```

Comment: Why do you use completely different arguments on the cli and in the scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Scheduled task that triggers on 1:30 PM every if System is Active and below i described how i did it..

First Create a .bat file having code bellow

```
start /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:/xampp/htdocs/Version/I7/application/controllers/cli/Reminders.php
```

then go to `Windows Task Scheduler` and From right side pane click `Create Task` then fill simple attributes like name and other things in `Action` Tab Create a new Action and then select run a program then select the batch file we created before..

go to `Triggers` tab create new `trigger` according to your specification fill out all the fields and save the task.

Comment: I have completed what you advised and it is still not executing it? Is the code in the .bat file correct?

Comment: code is correct because it runs everyday on my machine. you have to restart your machine after creating schedule task.

Comment: I have restarted my machine and the reminder is still not performing?

Comment: what `time` you are setting in trigger ??

Comment: 12.30 Daily. I assume you can test run it at any time by clicking "Run" in selected item?

Comment: have you added bat file in action tab ?

Comment: In the Action Tab, in program I have the following: C:\xampp\htdocs\Version\I7\application\controllers\cli\Cron.bat

Comment: is Action set to `start a Program` and have tried running bat program manually ?

Comment: Yes Action is set to 'start a program'. By running it manually do you mean by clicking "Run" in selected item? If so, yes.

Comment: I put the following in the .bat file and it works. **cd C:/xampp/htdocs/Version/I7
php index.php cli/reminders**